How to make the first and last item non-scrollable, but only the middle section?
I need to show a list of numbers in a LazyRow (I picked lazyrow as there can be like 200 numbers). The first number and the last number should be always visible on the left and right side. The rest of the numbers need to be able to horizontally scroll.
How can I achieve this?
See attached image: black border sticky/fixed, grey border scrollable.

I tried putting LazyRow inside a Row, but it does not work unless I predefine the LazyRow's item width (which I don't know as the numbers will be dynamic, could be 5 digit or more).
I also tried using stickyHeader but it does not allow me to use that for both left and right side, especially if there are only 1 or 2 numbers between the first and last.

Using a LazyRow inside a Row is a good approach, the only thing that is missing is the weight modifier on the LazyRow.
That modifier distributes the space among its siblings according to the given weight. All siblings that do not have a weight modifier take up as much space as needed. If only the LazyRow has a weight modifier that means that the other elements of the surrounding Row are measured first and the LazyRow will then take up all the remaining space. This way the first and the last element will always have enough space left so they can be displayed.
You could use something like this:
Row {
    val first = list.firstOrNull() ?: return@Row
    MyItem(first)

    val middleList = list.subList(1, list.lastIndex)
    if (middleList.isNotEmpty())
        LazyRow(
            modifier = Modifier.weight(1f),
        ) {
            items(middleList) { MyItem(it) }
        }

    val last = list.subList(1, list.size).lastOrNull() ?: return@Row
    MyItem(last)
}

list is the list of items to display and MyItem is the composable to display such an item.

Thank you, but unfortunately that was my first idea, and it still crashes on me with the message it cannot do anything with infinite measurements. I appreciate the feedback.

Ah, I wasn't aware you tried it with the weight modifier, would have been good if you included that in your question from the start. Well, then the problem must be somewhere else because this code definitely works as intended. Please create a new project and copy the code from my answer into the MainActivity's setContent lambda. You need to replace MyItem with Text and you can try it out with this list: val list = List(200) { "$it" }. When that works you can compare what you did differently in your old code to narrow it down where the problem actually lies.

Just to rule out the obvious: You didn't apply the fillMaxWidth or fillMaxSize modifier or something similar to any item in the LazyRow, did you?

Thank you, turns out the problem comes when I try to add Modifier.height(IntrinsicSize.Min) to the Row(). Which I wanted to do in order to be able to use VerticalDivider after the first and before the last item.

Not yet, but i will need to make sure that if there are only like 1-3 items, they need to take up the entire available space.

Is you question sufficiently answered then? The problems you still have seem to be unrelated to your original question how a LazyRow can be made with a fixed first and last element.

The original question was answered yes. I marked it.

"they need to take up the entire available space": Have a look at Modifier.fillParentMaxWidth() that can be used in the items' lambda, maybe that helps.
